# No module named 'quandl' after pip3 install, using Spyder on Mac

Tags: installation, module, python-3.9, quandl, import-module

I'm trying to write a script that requires quandl. I have pip3 installed it via terminal however when I go to import it in my script I get the error:

> ```
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Quandl'
> ```

Before anyone mentions about in python3 it is lower case...

> ```
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'quandl'
> ```

...that doesn't work either.

I checked where python3 was installed, and where pip3 was installing things:

> ```
> $ which -a python3
> ```
>
> ```
> /usr/bin/python3
> ```
>
> ```
> $ which -a pip3
> ```
>
> ```
> /usr/bin/pip3
> ```

I don't think there is a problem here, but I'm not great with these things.

I also checked that it was in fact installed correctly. Everything seems to be above board and it even appears in the pip3 list:

> ```
> $ pip3 list
> ```
>
> ```
> Package            Version
> ```
>
> ```
> ------------------ ---------
> ```
>
> ```
> ...
> ```
>
> ```
> Quandl             3.7.0
> ```
>
> ```
> ...
> ```

I'm using python version 3.9.6. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling quandl. I've also tried updating python and every aspect of my IDE generally. Nothing works. Please help, I just want to get on with my project at this point.